# URI::InvalidURIError when parsing arguments to URL

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=#{user}&count=#{number} (URI::InvalidURIError)

My args being parsed in from command line are

```
name = ARGV[1]
number = ARGV[2]
```

Would appreciate some help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attempting to interpolate values into the URL, do the right thing and let Ruby handle the possible encoding of special characters:

```
require 'uri'

name = 'foo'
number = 1

uri = URI('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true')
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(
  Hash[
    URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)
  ].merge('name' => name, 'count' => number)
)

puts uri
```

After running, this is the output:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&name=foo&count=1
```

While 90% of the time you can put a value into the URL using interpolation it'll work, there are times you'll need to include a character that needs to be encoded, and your URL will generate an error when you try to use it.

The [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) class follows the spec for how the query should be encoded, so you won't run into those problems.

Breaking it down, you can see what happens:

```
uri.query
# => "include_entities=true&include_rts=true"
URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)
# => [["include_entities", "true"], ["include_rts", "true"]]
Hash[URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)]
# => {"include_entities"=>"true", "include_rts"=>"true"}
Hash[URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)].merge('name' => name, 'count' => number)
# => {"include_entities"=>"true", "include_rts"=>"true", "name"=>"foo", "count"=>1}
URI.encode_www_form(Hash[URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)].merge('name' => name, 'count' => number))
# => "include_entities=true&include_rts=true&name=foo&count=1"
```

---

EDIT:

> undefined method `decode_www_form' for URI:Module (NoMethodError)
>
> im using ruby 1.9

Look at the [Addressable](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/) gem. It's very nicely done, and has more features then the built-in URI class:

```
require 'addressable/uri'

name = 'foo'
number = 1

uri = Addressable::URI.parse('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true')
uri.query_values = uri.query_values.merge('name' => name, 'count' => number)

puts uri
```

Which looks like:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=1&include_entities=true&include_rts=true&name=foo
```

Comment: So I take it this will work with arguments...

Comment: undefined method `decode_www_form' for URI:Module (NoMethodError)

Comment: `decode_www_form` is a class method for URI, and has been [since Ruby 1.9.2](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html). Are you running a version of Ruby prior to 1.9.2? If not, you didn't implement the code example right.

Comment: Look into the Addressable gem then. See the added sample in my answer.

Comment: run ruby -v get 1.8...so ill intsall 1.9..hopefully it works...

Comment: /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/request/multipart.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_BOUNDARY
./filename.rb:15: undefined method `decode_www_form' for URI:Module (NoMethodError)

Comment: Putting error messages without all the steps or code leading to them is worthless. Create another question to deal with this specific issue. I'd strongly recommend updating your Ruby as it is out of date and no longer supported. Use RVM or rbenv to manage the upgrade.